# Moving multiple files in different folder

Tags: macos, bash

I need make multiple folder having the name from file without extension with this command

```
for i in *.avi; do mkdir "${i%.*}"; done
```

I don't know how to mv the related file in the folder made...

Thanks for any help

Thanks. Let's say I want to do a general script to record on Textexpander which ask me for the file extension a sort of this :

```
echo "Type the suffix of the file follewe by enter:"
read ext
for i in *.ext
do
    mkdir "${i%.ext}"
    mv "$i" "${i%.ext}"
done
```

But this is not working.

Comment: `for i in *.avi; do mkdir "${i%.*}"; mv "$i" "${i%.*}"; done`??

Answer (score 3):

Use the `mv` command:

```
for i in *.avi
do 
    mkdir "${i%.*}"
    mv "$i" "${i%.*}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks.. Let's say I want make a general script to record on TextExpander which ask me for file extension like this I suppose: `echo "Type the suffix of the file followed by enter:"

Comment: Use the `read` command like this: `read -p "enter suffix: " input`. Then `echo $input` to see what was typed.